# how to compress size of image in Flutter

Tags: flutter

How can I(compress) the size of the image when I select it from the gallery or take it from the camera? Did Flutter have a package or ways to do it?

```
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  File _image;

  Future getImage() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

    setState(() {
      _image = image;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Image Picker Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _image == null
            ? Text('No image selected.')
            : Image.file(_image),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: getImage,
        tooltip: 'Pick Image',
        child: Icon(Icons.add_a_photo),
      ),
    );
  }
}`
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the getImage func you can use:

```
Future getImage() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
        source: ImageSource.gallery, imageQuality: 50, maxHeight: 600, maxWidth: 900);
    setState(() {
      _image = image;
    });
  }
```

You can set maximum resolution and image quality from 1 to 100.

Comment: I don't wanna change the image quality manually to become avoid lossing the quality I needs package or method to do this

Comment: I think if you set Max height and width you are good to go. This way you can be sure that the size will be the size you want.

Answer (score 3):

you can provide the width property and the quality in the call to pickImage function

```dart
   var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera, imageQuality: int, maxWidth: int);
```

the width is used to reduce the size, (width * height) of the image, and the quality is a fliter that will be used

Comment: alright but when get reduced the quality image won't be clear

Answer (score 2):

1. If you want fixed size, then use 'SizedBox' first,then add image as a child:

   SizedBox(
              height: 40,
              width: 40,
              child:  Image.asset("icons/coins.png", width: 100.0, height:100.0),
            ),
2. For dynamic size:
    imageQuality: 70, , maxWidth: 100
3. If you are extract image from API, then can use maxRadius:

Example:

```
child: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage('apilink/StudentsPhoto/S6247.jpg'),
                    maxRadius: 30,
                  ),
```